# Number of columns according to screen size?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Please consider the following layout for a page. There are three columns inside a container.

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem i want to solve is that for mobile screen sizes i want to hide the middle column. For screen sizes greater than mobile i.e tablet, laptops and desktops i want to show the middle column. How can i achieve this. All three columns should be of equal width.

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap includes [responsive utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities) to hide or show elements are specific breakpoints. The visible classes are `visible-xs-*`, `visible-sm-*`, `visible-md-*`, and `visible-lg-*`. The hidden classes are `hidden-xs`, `hidden-sm`, `hidden-md`, and `hidden-lg`.

If you want to hide an element for small and extra small resolutions, you can do something like `<div class="col hidden-xs hidden-sm">`

**[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/T7ERKwcLWT)**

Answer (score 0):

By using css, you can hide anything. See below:

```
    <div class = "container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        </div>
        <div class="col column-to-hide">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


 <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px){ 
        .column-to-hide{
           display:none;
        }
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: What do you mean using bootstrap? You can add class to your column that you want to hide, then add css code to your .css file or to the same pahe where you have html.

Comment: if your bootstrap is stronger than this css code, change display:none; to display:none !important;

Comment: Feel free to change this max-width: 500px as your screen size for iphone or Ipad.

Comment: is there a way to achieve without using custom styles but purely bootstrap classes?

Comment: Bootstrap put columns in different order  for small screen, it doesn't hide them.